# Devise: How to use remember_me cookie after user sign out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies, devise

I'm working on a `Rails 4.2` Application and using `devise` gem for authentication.

For `remember_me` feature, devise generates a cookie `remember_user_token` which gets destroy after `sign_out`.

Is there a way such that `Devise` should not destroy `remember_user_token` ?

I tried to `false` the below `config` in the `initializer`

`config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = false`

But it didn't help.

I need that cookie after sign-out such that it will populate the login form.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Coupling authentication with form pre-filling isn't necessarily a good idea. You can store the login in a cookie upon successful login. You can override the `create` method in your `SessionsController`, call `super` to call `Devise::SessionsController#create` and pass it a block. The block will be executed after a successful log in and will receive the user as a parameter.

```rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super do |user|
      cookies[:login] = user.login
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the low down on cookie store. First off, everything in a cookie is there permanently once it's set or until the user deletes the cookie manually somehow. This means, that if you set user_id and user_group_id, it's there for good in the cookie until updated or deleted. This is different from a session since the session is like ram on a computer, once the browser is closed, the session closes with it as well as all of it's data.

1. So, this means that when you log out your user, you need to specify that their cookie empties anything you don't wan't it to have. When your user logs in, you set anything that you want the user to have while they are logged in. So, since the session and cookie are separate things completely, they never interact together unless you choose to make them. So your session will never dump its self into the cookie store unless you make it do that.
2. Every time your users go to your site, you could have a single handshake that makes sure that the cookie matches the db if necessary. Otherwise, you could have differing data what only gets updated on login or what not and without the handshake, the user would have to keep logging in to make sure they are still valid which defeats the purpose of having a cookie in the first place.
3. The downside of client side cookie storage is security concerns. Depending on how you use the cookie to store data, a person could hijack somebodies cookie on your site and pretend they are them. This can be avoided by careful design, but just assume that whatever is in your cookie store is fair game to everybody so use it carefully and for only non secret data.

Hope this helps!